# Variables continously equal nan when using a while loop

Tags: c

This question is revolving around the Autopilot mode, or the else in my main method. When I have while(time != -1), all of my variables will print as nan. However, when I set the loop a finite number of times ie:<150, my variables are printed as actual numbers. Is there any way I can fix this? If my explanation doesn't make sense I can try my best to reword it.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
struct _stats
{
    double altitude, velocity, mass, fuel, acceleration;
};
typedef struct _stats Stats;

void updateStats(Stats *a, double thrust, int time)
{
    a->acceleration += (thrust / a->mass -1.6) * time;
    a->mass -= thrust / 3000.0;
    a->fuel -= thrust / 3000.0;
    a->velocity += a->acceleration * time;
    a->altitude += a->velocity * time;
}

double thrustAllowed(Stats a, double thrust)
{
    if (thrust/1000 <= 45 && thrust <= (3000 * a.fuel))
    {
        return thrust;
    }
    else
        return (3000*a.fuel)/1000;
}

double thrustControl(Stats *a)
{
    double thrust = 0;
    printf("aaaaa%f\n", a->altitude);
    if (a->altitude > 5)
    {
        a->acceleration = ((a->velocity * a->velocity) - (-.9 * -.9)) / (2.0 * (a->altitude - 5.0));
        thrust = a->mass * (a->acceleration + 1.6);
        //printf("%f", thrust);
        return thrust;
    }
    else
        thrust = -a->mass * -1.6 * (a->velocity / -.9);
    return thrust;
}

int main(void)
{
    int time = 0;
    double thrust = 0;
    char response = ' ';
    bool alt = true;
    Stats rocket;
    rocket.altitude = 150000;
    rocket.velocity = -325;
    rocket.mass = 9000;
    rocket.fuel = 1800;
    rocket.acceleration = 0;
    printf("Enter G for Game Mode and any other character for Autopilot: ");
    scanf("%c", &response);
    if (response == 'G')
    {
        FILE* inputFile = fopen("simulation.csv", "wt");
        if (!inputFile)
        {
            printf("Unable to open file.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        while (time < 150)
        {
            time++;
            fprintf(inputFile, "Enter a Thrust in kN: ");
            printf("Enter a Thrust in kN: ");
            scanf("%lf", &thrust);
            fprintf(inputFile, "%f", thrust);
            printf("%f", thrust);
            thrust = thrust * 1000;
            if (thrustAllowed(rocket, thrust) == thrust)
            {
                updateStats(&rocket, thrust, time);
                fprintf(inputFile, "\nThrust: %.1f  Altitude : %.1f  Velocity : %.1f  Mass : %.1f  Fuel : %.1f\n", thrust, rocket.altitude, rocket.velocity, rocket.mass, rocket.fuel);
                printf("\nThrust: %.1f  Altitude : %.1f  Velocity : %.1f  Mass : %.1f  Fuel : %.1f\n", thrust, rocket.altitude, rocket.velocity, rocket.mass, rocket.fuel);
                if (rocket.altitude <= 0)
                {
                    if (rocket.velocity <= 0 && rocket.velocity >= -1)
                    {
                        fprintf(inputFile, "Soft Landing!!!");
                        printf("Soft Landing!!!");
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fprintf(inputFile, "You broked it");
                        printf("You broked it");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                fprintf(inputFile, "Thrust must be <= %.1f\n", thrustAllowed(rocket, thrust));
                printf("Thrust must be <= %.1f\n", thrustAllowed(rocket, thrust));

            }

        }
        fclose(inputFile);
    }
    else
    {
        FILE* inputFile = fopen("simulation.csv", "wt");
        if (!inputFile)
        {
            printf("Unable to open file.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        printf("\n\n\ncccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc %f\n", rocket.altitude);
        while (time != -1)
        {
            time++;
            thrust = thrustControl(&rocket, time);
            //printf("%f\n", rocket.altitude);
            updateStats(&rocket, thrust, time);
            fprintf(inputFile, "\nThrust: %.1f  Altitude : %.1f  Velocity : %.1f  Mass : %.1f  Fuel : %.1f\n", thrust, rocket.altitude, rocket.velocity, rocket.mass, rocket.fuel);
            printf("\nThrust: %.1f  Altitude : %.1f  Velocity : %.1f  Mass : %.1f  Fuel : %.1f\n", thrust, rocket.altitude, rocket.velocity, rocket.mass, rocket.fuel);
            if (rocket.altitude <= 0)
            {
                if (rocket.velocity <= 0 && rocket.velocity >= -1)
                {
                    fprintf(inputFile, "Soft Landing!!!");
                    printf("Soft Landing!!!");
                    time = -1;
                }
                else
                {
                    fprintf(inputFile, "You broked it");
                    printf("You broked it");
                    time = -1;
                }
            }
            //printf("time %i", time);
        }
        fclose(inputFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Carcigenicate Doesn't the if statement check to make sure a->altitude is > 5 first though?

Comment: I was going to test your program but it doesn't compile: `thrustControl` takes 1 argument but you have passed 2.

Comment: One note is that if `rocket.altitude` never reaches zero, then `time` will continue to increment until it overflows, which is undefined behavior.

Comment: The math in `updateStats` also looks questionable: you multiply everything by `time` which is the total elapsed time since launch.  Shouldn't it be "delta t", the time elapsed since the last update?